# PHP, remove string using "pattern"

Tags: php, string, substr

I have the following url which will always have a color variable attached:

```
http://www.example.com/?new=yes&color=red&shape=square
```

How would I, using PHP, remove everything at the end; starting at *&color*, so I am left with the following:

```
http://www.example.com/?new=yes
```

Comment: What if the order of the parameters differs?

Comment: They won't. Very few links, this is just for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is:

```
$url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '&color='));
```

However, this is good only for the specific case -- it would probably be a good idea to do something a little more robust. For example, splitting the URL, getting the key/value pairs into an array, removing those you don't want (or removing everything except those you want) and recreating the URL.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, perfect job!

Comment: What if the needle is not contained?

Comment: @Gumbo: Bad things happen. But I gathered the impression from the OP's comment that this is throwaway code, and it's hard to argue against a single LOC if that's true.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the combination of [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) & [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). You can also use [http_build_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) & [http_build_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php), though these require [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http).

Comment: And thanks for the reply Brad, will take a look at those functions

Comment: While this approach is what I view as "most correct" (and better than the shameful hack that is my answer), it has a big practical flaw: `http_build_url` and friends is not built in by default.

Comment: @Jon: Indeed. Part of the PECL lib, though intended as the most "bullet-proof" solution.

Comment: I 'm only saying because the other day I was going to recommend exactly this for another question; when I found out that it wasn't built in and my "example" code was going above 1 screen size on its quest for correctness, I gave up.

Comment: @Jon: I hear ya, I've had those days... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/?new=yes&color=red&shape=square";

$url_parts = explode("&", $url);

$thePartYouWant = $url_parts[0];
```